# "fatal error LNK1561: entry point must be defined" error from MASM32 in very simple program

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, masm32, coff

Fixed; here's the fixed code (doesn't do anything and crashes, but it assembles, which is the point):

```
.686P
.MODEL FLAT
.CODE
_START:
    MOV al, 255
END _START
```

I also discovered I had to use the `/c` switch with ml and then link separately with `/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE`.

---

Just rediscovered x86 assembly and MASM32 and am getting myself reacquainted with the basics. I wrote a short, pointless program thus, to see if I could assemble anything:

```
.686P
.MODEL FLAT
.CODE
START:
    MOV al, 255
END
```

I ran `ml /coff test.asm` and got this output:

```
Microsoft (R) Macro Assembler Version 6.14.8444
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1981-1997.  All rights reserved.

 Assembling: test.asm
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 5.12.8078
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1992-1998. All rights reserved.

"test.obj"
"/OUT:test.exe"
LINK : fatal error LNK1561: entry point must be defined
```

I read online that START was the name of the entry point. Have I done this wrong or this is a different problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have MASM, but usually the entry point is `_start:`, not `START:`.

See [this MASM example program](http://snipplr.com/view/4526/simple-masm-program/).

Comment: Thanks! I did some more research and as well as that being correct (_START also works), I forgot to end the program with `END _START`. It now assembles.

Answer (score 1):

That END directive is used to set the entry point:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxy1fb5k(v=vs.80).aspx

So END should be END START. The entry point label can be any valid label name.